# I am not able to reorder the blocks in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

I have more than 200 blocks in my drupal website. Right now I am not able to reorder the blocks from the admin end.

I can drag and drop the blocks. So there is no problem with my js (I think so). After saving the blocks, selected blocks went to the previous position. (Weight is not updating.)

Any Idea?

Comment: It might be a js issue. Have you tried setting the weights manually by clicking the 'Show row weights' link and change the weight dropdowns?

Comment: Yes.. I tried to changing the weight manually.. That also not working properly..

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried using the weights manually but it's not saving them to the db.

Answer (score 6):

Try increasing the `max_input_vars` value in `php.ini`. Setting that value to 2000 worked in my case (Windows Server 2008/IIS/MySQL/PHP5.3 and over 200 D7 blocks).

Troubleshooting tips for WIMP:
In `php.ini`, set:

```
error_log=C:\Windows\temp\php_errors.log
```

In `php_errors.log`, look for a message such as:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I didn't think about how every weight is being submitted at once. Your fix worked :)

Comment: It not only works for blocks but for taxonomy terms as well.